# questions about php mysql update

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is to check product availability and update the product quantity if the product is available. Can the code below work properly to avoid concurrent update? Thanks

```
     $query= "START TRANSACTION; select pd_qty from tbl_product where pd_id='$pid' and pd_qty=0";
     $result=mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error()); 
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     shortage=1;
     }
     if (shortage!=1)){
     $query= "update tbl_product set pd_qty = .......;
     insert into tbl_order ....; "   
     mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error()); 
     COMMIT;"
     } else {
     $query= "COMMIT;"
     mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error()); 
     }
```

Comment: it can't work, period. php/mysql don't allow multiple queries in the same `query()` call, so you can't start a transaction and then do your select in the same call. and beyond that, you haven't locked any records, so even though it's in a transaction, nothing will stop a parallel query from fiddling with the records behind your back.

Comment: Are you asking whether `mysql_query` can execute multiple queries at the same time?

Comment: You should always make sure that the syntax is still valid when you are shortening your code. In you `if` block you have on the one hand a syntax error at ` COMMIT; "` and you don't call `commit` there.

Comment: I want to check product availability and deduct the product for sales. I am worrying that when two clients operate at the mean time when pd_qty=1, shortage cannot be detected and updates will be performed two times, causing problems. So I want to use transaction to avoid such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code like this, can it work now?

```
mysql_query('BEGIN');  
query="select pd_qty from tbl_product where pd_id='$pid' and pd_qty=0 for update";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error()); 
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
shortage=1;
}
if (shortage!=1)){
$query= "update tbl_product set pd_qty = .......;"   
mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error()); 
$query= "insert into tbl_order ....; "
mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_query('COMMIT');
```